# VSC - IntelliSense marks boolean operator as errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

IntelliSense is incorrectly marking boolean operators (`and`, `or`, etc.) As errors. Here is an example:

[image]

This is my `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Visual C++, it looks like you need to add [`#include <iso646.h>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=msvc-160#operator-keyword-for-).

> C++ specifies `bitand` as an alternative spelling for `&`. In C, the alternative spelling is provided as a macro in the <iso646.h> header. In C++, the alternative spelling is a keyword; use of <iso646.h> or the C++ equivalent  is deprecated. In Microsoft C++, the /permissive- or /Za compiler option is required to enable the alternative spelling.

After including the header file, it no longer errors:

[image: Example]

[Wikipedia also cites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens):

> Some compilers, such as Microsoft Visual C++ have, at least in the past, required the header to be included in order to use these identifiers.